# How to get the maximum width & height size image when loading several images before loading them completely?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am loading images of different size and then images are scaled and border is drawn for each image as shown in below link,

http://web.s4spk.com/irfan/test.swf

I want that border of images to be of the same width and height and for that I need to find out the max width and height size image before loading all the images. Is there any way that I can know the width and height of an image before loading it completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hard way:** Use the `ByteArray` class and load your images as byte data (`URLLoader` with type set to `BINARY`). Load in the first few bytes to read in the header. In the header of the image, you can parse out the width and height.

You'll need to be familiar with the specifications of the image type you're using (PNG is found at http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/) and have a working knowledge of bytes (Thibault Imbert is writing an excellent book on the subject: http://www.bytearray.org/?p=711)

**Easy way:** Load in all your images, but don't add them to the stage. They won't be shown, and you can check the width/height and draw your border as needed.

**Even easier way:** Have a fixed border size and scale your images as they're loaded

Comment: i know the easy and even easier way but will go with hard way as i can not wait for all images to be loaded and then events are added to gallery. My events are added before, hence i would try byteArray.